# Adding non-accordion element by button klick

Tags: jquery, accordion

I got the following problem:

On [this](http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/jquery-accordion-menu-redux/) page (it's /not/ mine, I'm taking it just as an example) you can see under

3. non-accordion (standard expandable menu)

a ,as the name tells, a standard expandable menu. Now the question that I got:

Is it possible to add by e.g. clicking on a button, to add another menu item, so that instead of 5 items, we got than 6, 7, 8... etc.

If yes, what would be the best way to realize it ? What would be required (e.g. an live()/Event handler)?

Comment: You forgot to include the page you're referencing.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, ...my apologies *blush*

here the link: 
http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/jquery-accordion-menu-redux/

Answer (score 0):

You can add elements to that menu with jQuery clone(). After adding new element , you might have to rebind/restart the accordion effect/function though, otheriwse it might not work on new element.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Can you tell me how the rebind/restart of the accordion can be achieved ?

Comment: exactly the way it was done the first time- by calling initMenus() i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Having a new item appear in an accordion section does not require resetting the accordion control; however, adding a new header section does.

You can "restart" an accordion by first destroying it and then recreating it, using something like

```
$('#myaccordion').accordion('destroy').accordion({ autoHeight: false, active: false, collapsible: true, navigation: true });
```

If you want to keep the same section open after you recreate it, you'll need to enable navigation and also set the hash of the window to the hash of the section through a click handler.